# Debug flutter app throws out of memory error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

whenever I debug a simple flutter app, it always throws - out of memory error with below logs. I'm using Android Studio 4.0, Flutter 1.17.2, and Java 8.

If I run the Gradle task assembledebug from the command line it builds successfully.

I've set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1024M" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in gradle.properties. It drives me crazy , Please help

Logs:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
`|c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\zone.cc: 90: error: Out of memor y. version=2.8.3 (stable) (Tue May 26 18:39:38 2020 +0200) on "windows_x64"`